# Grafana: Define alert on a ratio

Tags: alert, grafana, influxdb

Is there any way to define an alert based on a condition that describes a ratio in Grafana?

For example I have a query that counts the failed HTTP requests and another one that holds the total number of requests. Is there a way to define an alert with the following condition

```
WHEN (query_failed/query_total,5m,now) IS ABOVE 0.75
```

Unfortunately I cannot use Grafana's transformation feature since lovely Grafana prompts me with the following

```
Transformations are not supported in alert queries
```

I am using Influx 1.7.4

Comment: Out of curiosity: it is not possible to perform this calculation with the InfluxDB query language?

Comment: I was using 1.7 and you cannot combine fields of different measurements in the same query in that version. In 1.8 you can use the new Flux query engine and perform math across measurements. This is what I ended up doing in the end. Upgrade, Define query across measurements. Define alert on the query.